# Elixir Event Handler

Tags: python, pylons, python-elixir

I want to use the @after_insert decorator of Elixir, but i can't access the Session within the model. Since i have autocommit set to False, i can't commit any changes in the event handler. Is there any best practice how to deal with that?

The Code I used to build model, database connection etc. are mostly taken off the documentations.

The desired method:

```
class Artefact(Entity):
[...]
    @after_insert
    def make_signature(self):
        self.signature = '%s-%s' % (self.artefact_type.title.upper()[:3], self.id)
```

All the Session initialization is done in the **init**.py in the same directory.

When I then call:

```
Session.update(self)
Session.commit()
```

I get an error that Session is undefined.
Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you imported Session?

`from packagename import Session`

at the top of your model file should do the trick. Packagename is the directory name.